# Spring Data - Using property values in projections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, projection

I have Spring Data Rest Application where I created a projection like this

```
@Projection(name = "UserWithAvatar", types = { User.class })
public interface UserWithAvatar {
    String getName();
    String getEmail();

    @Value("${app.url}/pictures/#{target.imageId}")
    String getAvatar();
}
```

The non working part is the `getAvatar`, it generates a url for seeing the picture.
However this `${app.url}` is not working inside the projection.
How would I add this application.properties value in there?

Comment: `@Value("#{${app.url}/pictures/#{target.imageId}}")` or something like that. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language

Comment: @AlanHay I tried `@Value("#{ ${app.url} + '/pictures/' + target.imageId}")`, it did not work unfortunately. It returns a `EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'` error then.

Comment: @Deadpool They do in projections https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open

Comment: Maybe access `systemProperties` direcly `@Value("#{ systemProperties['app.url']  + '/pictures/' + target.imageId  }")`?

Comment: @MartinBG Apparently the `application.properties` values is not in `systemProperties`, or something else is failing with your example. 
`Property or field 'systemProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.data.projection.SpelEvaluatingMethodInterceptor$TargetWrapper' - maybe not public or not valid?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@environment.getProperty('app.url')` inside `#{}` block. It works on Spring Boot 2.3.0, i'm not sure about older versions.

Example:

```
@Value("#{target.pictureUrl ?: @environment.getProperty('app.url') + 'static/default-avatar.png'}")
String getAvatarUrl();
```